# Beamer block color depending on section

Tags: beamer, color, block

My beamer file contain 4 section and in any section some block environment. I would like to create a command that defines a color for block of in specific section depending on the number of that section.
I think I must use `ifthen` package:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{ifthen}
...
\newcommand{\myColor}{%
    \ifthenelse{\thesection = 1}{color1}{%
     \ifthenelse{\thesection = 2}{color2}{%
     \ifthenelse{\thesection = 3}{color3}{%
      \ifthenelse{\thesection = 3}{color4}{%
         DimGray}%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\section{first section}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}[A  block of the first section]
        Something about this example of the first kind.
    \end{block}
    \end{frame}
   \section{second section}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{block}[A  block of the second section]
        Something about this example of the second kind.
    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but I don't know how to involve `block` environment.
any suggestion would be appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\AtBeginSection{%
    \ifnum\value{section}=1
        \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=red}
    \fi
    \ifnum\value{section}=2
        \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=green}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{A  block of the first section}
        Something about this example of the first kind.
    \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\section{second section}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{A  block of the second section}
        Something about this example of the second kind.
    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Second version**

This approach is a bit closer to the syntax you envisioned in your question.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\definecolor{zz1}{rgb}{.8,.2,.2}
\definecolor{zz2}{rgb}{.7,.9,.1}
\definecolor{zz3}{rgb}{.6,.4,.8}

\AtBeginSection{%
   \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=zz\thesection}
}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{A  block of the first section}
        Something about this example of the first kind.
    \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\section{second section}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{A  block of the second section}
        Something about this example of the second kind.
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\section{third section}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{A  block of the second section}
        Something about this example of the second kind.
    \end{block}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```